How to do grid independence/ mesh convergence test on WaterLily package in Julia languaga?
We are exploring WaterLily for fluid simulations but we are unable to figure out how to change the grid number and grid uniformity in WaterLily. Since we can't figure out the grid settings, we are not being able to do a mesh convergence or grid independence test for our simulations.
I tried looking at the source codes and the tutorials of WaterLily on YouTube, expecting a guideline on how to manually edit the grid specifics.

The reference paper might also contain hints. "WaterLily implements the governing equation using a finite-volume approach on a uniform Cartesian grid with staggered velocity-pressure variable placement. Since all grid cells are identical, no grid information is stored. ..." or "To test different grid resolutions, we select L = { 2⁶, 2⁷, 2⁸, 2⁹ } ..."
